# How can EOS prevent collusion of block producers?

Tags: block-producer

How can EOS prevent colluding to make it a more decentralized system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking  about how blockproducers make concenses ,aBFT (asynchronous Byzentene faluttolerent)

please follow this article 
http://www.information-age.com/gold-standard-security-distributed-systems-like-blockchain-123469395/

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent collusion, EOSIO, like many other chains, keeps all on-chain transactions public. Further, it natively supports a constitution through Ricardian clauses and a multisig "admin" account that has various privileges if a supermajority of BPs agree on using it. As such, there are certain rules that participants agree when using the blokchain. For instance, on the EOS mainnet, [there is a clause](https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/governance/blob/master/eosio.system/eosio.system-voteproducer-rc.md) that one implicitly agrees on when using the `voteproducer` command:

> ...
>
> I stipulate I have not and will not accept anything of value in exchange for these votes, on penalty of confiscation of these tokens, and other penalties.
>
> ...

Thus, this framework can be employed to reduce or prevent collusion, assuming this is possible. For further information about this, [the governance section](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#governance) in the whitepaper may provide more details.

---

However, you also ask:

> How can EOS prevent colluding to make it a more decentralized system?

I would note that collusion prevention is not necessarily conducive to creating a more decentralized system. For instance, Dan Larimer [mentions](https://twitter.com/bytemaster7/status/1046743226806349824):

> True decentralization is free market competition among different colluding groups.